# Custom keyboard with editable UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, contenteditable, rich-text-editor, inputview

Is is possible to use a custom keyboard with editable UIWebView for rich text editing (by setting inputView property, like on UITextView)?

It tried subclassing UIWebView and setting the inputView property to readwrite, but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

Note that this applies to editable WebView content (having HTML attribute contentEditable="true"), not HTML input fields.

Comment: hi do you get any lights ?? its sad that it don't work even with your try on readonly inputView. came to know its in apple doc that any subclass of UIResponder's inputView can be change and UIWebView is a subclass of UIResponder. i too need for web view rich editing. any lights ???

Answer (score 0):

it is a little bit too late but as I spent 3 hours looking for a work around I thought that I should share it with you.

You can use on screen keyboard implemented using HTML5 and CSS follow this link:
[JS Based on-screen keyboard for browser, like on cellphones and tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762431/js-based-on-screen-keyboard-for-browser-like-on-cellphones-and-tablets)

you can inject the code into the page using **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** when the **UIWebViewDelegate** calls the **webViewDidFinishLoad**

I hope that helps you