# .focus() enables caps lock in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, responsive-design

I focus to an input in my web-project. It works fine in web-browsers.

```
$("#my-search-input").focus();
```

When I test it in my mobile-browser (Chrome/Android), it opens keyboard caps-lock...which is not good for my AJAX-based application.

What is the reason for this and what is the **most proper way to ensure** keyboard will not be caps-lock?

Thank you.

Comment: its because you have auto-capitalize first letter setting enabledon your device.. theres nothing you can do currently to prevent this... well  besides using a custom css/js  keyboard thats a dom element instead of the native one

Comment: take a look at this answer for a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762431/js-based-on-screen-keyboard-for-browser-like-on-cellphones-and-tablets